# PyAutoGUI locate on screen function giving error on linux

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyautogui

When running the pyautogui.locateOnScreen() function it gives me the following error:

`scrot: invalid option -- 'z'`

Does anyone know why this might be happening?
I have scrot 0.8 installed and just running `scrot a.png` in the terminal works just fine. Running `scrot -z` gives the same`scrot: invalid option -- 'z'` error message.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when I run `scrot --help` then it shows `-z, --silent Prevent beeping`. `scrot -v` shows it is version 0.8. Linux Mint 19.2 (based on Ubuntu 18.04) Maybe there are two different `scrot`

Comment: I also see this error on Fedora 31 after installing `scrot-0.8-21.fc31.x86_64`, which doesn't provide a `-z` option. There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/372).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore it, or if it bothers you, fork or submit a PR to [pyscreeze](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze).

pyautogui [depends](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/__init__.py#L218) on the pyscreeze package to take cross-platform screenshots. On Linux, pyscreeze [uses](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L469) a command-line utility called [scrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot).

When pyscreeze shells out to scrot, it [passes](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L475) `-z`. This specifies `Prevent beeping` in *some* versions of scrot, but isn't always available. For instance, it's missing in Fedora's `scrot-0.8-21.fc31.x86_64`.

But `invalid option -- 'z'` isn't a fatal error. You can verify this by running `$ scrot -z` and seeing that a new timestamped screenshot appears in your working directory, despite the message. Or from Python, call `subprocess.call(['scrot', '-z'])`, and see that the return code is `0`.